# model view view controller C#

Tags: c#

I am writing a simple program in c# which asks the user to enter a number, then tells the user if the number is odd or even. my program works however wheni first enter the number nothing happens, i have to enter the number twice and then it tells me if the number is odd or even, im not very good at using the mvvc technique, so if anyone knows why this is happening and could help me that would be great.my code is below...

```
class CheckNumber
{
    protected String number;
    public void SetNumber(String newNumber)
    {
        number = newNumber;

    }
    public int Number()
    {
        int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (number % 2 == 1)                                //(number % 2 == 0) would test for even numbers(0 remainder)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Odd number");
        }

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Even number");
        }

        return number;
    }

}


 class CheckNumberController
{
    IView view;
    CheckNumber checkNumber;
    public CheckNumberController(IView theView, CheckNumber theCheckMark)
    {
        view = theView;
        checkNumber = theCheckMark;
    }
    public void Go()
    {
        view.Start();
        checkNumber.SetNumber(view.GetString("Please enter a number"));
        view.Show(checkNumber.Number());
        view.Stop();
    }

}


 class ConsoleView : IView
{
    public void Start()
    {
        Console.Clear();
    }
    public void Stop()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to finish");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    public String GetString(String prompt = "")
    {
        Console.WriteLine(prompt);
        return Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public Int32 GetInt(String prompt = "")
    {
        Console.WriteLine(prompt);
        return Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    public void Show<T>(T message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }

}


interface IView
{
    void Start();
    void Stop();
    String GetString(String prompt);
    Int32 GetInt(String prompt);
    void Show<T>(T message);

}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        new CheckNumberController(new ConsoleView(), new CheckNumber()).Go();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public String GetString(String prompt = "")
{
    Console.WriteLine(prompt);
    //return Console.ReadLine();
    return "error is here";
}
```

When calling GetString() method your again trying to get an input. Just comment and return string if you want.

Answer (score 2):

You're reading input twice. Firstly in the `CheckNumberController.Go()`

```
checkNumber.SetNumber(view.GetString("Please enter a number"));
```

And secondly in `CheckNumber.Number()`

```
int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

The latter should be:

```
int number = Convert.ToInt32(this.number);
```

As you want to work on the value you've already read and set, not an additional one

Answer (score 0):

The key is in this method:

```
public void Go()
{
    view.Start();
    checkNumber.SetNumber(view.GetString("Please enter a number"));
    view.Show(checkNumber.Number());
    view.Stop();
}
```

`SetNumber(string)` sets the protected field `number` in the CheckNumber class. However, when you call `view.Show<T>(T)`, you are calling the `Number()` method on the `CheckNumber` class, which ignores the stored variable and reads from the console again.